Idle time in execution
I am trying to improve the performance of a sluggish Spark Application.  The application reads various AVRO files, transforms them (including joins, aggregations, and unions), and writes to various Parquet files.
As a first step, I enabled logging and wrote a unit test. The unit test took 4.6 minutes to complete. Looking at the execution timeline (below), there was a 2-minute and 40-second period when no jobs were executed.

Is it true that no jobs were executed at this time? Are there other options/data points I need to look at to get the true answer to this question? If no jobs were truly executed, what happened at this time? Is it just query planning as indicated here?
